# User table shows NULL data on multi table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was practicing the multi table on mysql. While creating the table, null data appeared on 'user table'. The user table should contain user_id(auto_increment). user_name should appear on user_info table which is from orders table.

```
create table orders(
primary key (order_id),
order_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
order_no varchar(100) default null,
user_name varchar(100) not null,
product_name varchar(100) not null,
order_status enum('CART',  'DRAFT',  'NEW',  'IN PROCESS',  ' COMPLETED',  'FAILED' ) DEFAULT 'CART',
carete_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '注册时间');
```

Comment: users or orders table?!?

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? All you've shown us is some code to create an empty table.

Comment: sy just edited the code, i'm pretty new to use this web :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any code which would insert anything into the "users" table, so I'm not sure why you would expect it to contain any data?

Your line

```
select distinct user_name from orders;
```

just after the create statement for the users table will simply display a list on screen. Perhaps you meant to write

```
insert into users (user_name) select distinct user_name  from orders;
```

This will actually add some rows to the users table.

Comment: ho, thank you so much. I'm just wondering the same thing like you said before. I was watching the tutorial video and they might missed that.

Comment: No problem...if the answer has helped you, please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick next to the answer so it turns green) - thankyou :-)